# how to manipulate connectionstring in app.config file?

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config, application-settings

I am trying to set `connectionstring` at runtime. What I need is set `datasource` at runtime and restart application. I found some approaches in google but the problem is `app.config` backs to default value after `Application.Restart();`

I tried to save `connectionstring` in `settings.cs` and `app.config` both but it doesn't work for me.
this is my code:

```
public void setConnectionString()
    {
        try
        {
            string str = string.Empty;

            str = string.Format(@"Data Source={0}; Initial Catalog=CRM01_DB; UID= {1}; PWD={2}", Default.DataSource, Default.UID, Default.UPass);

            this["CRM01_DBConnectionString"] = str;
            Default.Save();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["CRM01_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString = str;
            config.Save();
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

            Thread.Sleep(100);

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

I didn't get any errors but when application starts the `connectionstrig` has default value

Answer (score 0):

If you testing this code from VS it might not work (and probably won't).

When running from VS the actually program that is executed is `<your_program>.vshost.exe` and the corresponding `.config` file is named `<your_program>.vshost.exe.config` and you should check your changes there.

But..

VS keep the original `.config` and `.vshost.exe.config` synchronized so you don't see your changes.

To test if the code works try it from outside VS or uncheck `Enabled the Visual Studio hosting process` (`Properties` -> `Debug`) (keep in mind that it has [implications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx))

[image]

Comment: @mohammadboluki I did try it. Works like a charm